# Cannot fetch Url that start with `https://` using urllib.urlopen

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, urllib

My program  is working fine for url that start with http:// but if https: is matched by regex it gave me an error stating that `Name or services unknown`.Can urllib open `https://` if yes how can i fix my code if no .What should i use .

```
import sys
import urllib
import urlparse
import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
def process(url):
    proxies = {"http":"http://proxy4.nehu.ac.in:3128"}
    page  = urllib.urlopen(url)
    text = page.read()
    page.close()
    soup = BeautifulSoup(text)
    file=open('s.txt','w') 
    for tag in soup.findAll('a', href=True):
        tag['href'] = urlparse.urljoin(url, tag['href'])
        print tag['href']
        file.write('\n')
        file.write(tag['href'])
        file.close()
        file=open('s.txt','r')
    for line in file:
        if re.match(ur'(?i)\b((?:https?://|www\d{0,3}[.]|[a-z0-9.\-]+[.][a-z]{2,4}/)(?:[^\s()<>]+|\(([^\s()<>]+|(\([^\s()<>]+\)))*\))+(?:\(([^\s()<>]+|(\([^\s()<>]+\)))*\)|[^\s`!()\[\]{};:\'".,<>?\xab\xbb\u201c\u201d\u2018\u2019]))',line):
        print line
        page = urllib.urlopen(line)
        text = page.read()
        page.close()
        soup = BeautifulSoup(text)
    with open('newfile.txt','a') as file2:
            file2.write('\n ----------------- \n')
            file2.write(line)
            file2.write('\n ----------------- \n')
            for tag in soup.findAll('a', href=True):
                tag['href'] = urlparse.urljoin(line, tag['href'])
                print tag['href']

                file2.write('\n')
                file2.write(tag['href'])

       file.close()


       def main():
           if len(sys.argv) == 1:
              print 'No url !!'      
              sys.exit(1)
           for url in sys.argv[1:]:
              process(url)

      main()
```

This is the URL from my txt file:

```
https://support.makemytrip.com/MyAccount/MyTripReward/DashBoard
```

This error is shown:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "myurl.py", line 67, in <module>
main()
File "myurl.py", line 65, in main
process(url)
File "myurl.py", line 40, in process
page = urllib.urlopen(line)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib.py", line 84, in urlopen
return opener.open(url)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib.py", line 205, in open
return getattr(self, name)(url)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib.py", line 342, in open_http
h.endheaders(data)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 940, in endheaders
self._send_output(message_body)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 803, in _send_output
self.send(msg)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 755, in send
self.connect()
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 736, in connect
self.timeout, self.source_address)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 551, in create_connection
for res in getaddrinfo(host, port, 0, SOCK_STREAM):
IOError: [Errno socket error] [Errno -2] Name or service not known
```

Comment: Can you show the full error message, and give an example URL that causes this problem?

Comment: This might not work, but try escaping the `/` (so, put a \ before each /)

Comment: i edited my question with The Error @Evert

Comment: why downvote ? .......................

Comment: @TerryA the reqx is matching http: and https , what is the difference if i put `\\`  before each  `/` . This reqx i just copied from existing one.

Comment: that `if re.match(ur` line is not doing anything as posted, check your indentation and re-post

Comment: one quick look ath the documentation of urliib https://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib.html could have showed you that it is able to open https

Comment: @RolfofSaxony this is my `re.match(ur'(?i)\b((?:https?://|www\d{0,3}[.]|[a-z0-9.\-]+[.][a-z]{2,4}/)(?:[^\s()<>]+|\(([^\s()<>]+|(\([^\s()<>]+\)))*\))+(?:\(([^\s()<>]+|(\([^\s()<>]+\)))*\)|[^\s`!()\[\]{};:\'".,<>?\xab\xbb\u201c\u201d\u2018\u2019]))',line):`

Comment: @Stophface The context parameter may be set to a ssl.SSLContext.
How do i config this . should i just add this to `urlopen(url,proxies=NONE,ssl.SSLContext)`

Comment: @ShailangKharsati Did you at least try my attempt?

Comment: @TerryA i tried it is not working `re.match(ur'(?i)\b((?:https?:\/\/|www\d{0,3}[.]|[a-z0-9.\-]+[.][a-z]{2,4}\/)(?:[^\s()<>]+|\(([^\s()<>]+|(\([^\s()<>]+\)))*\))+(?:\(([^\s()<>]+|(\([^\s()<>]+\)))*\)|[^\s`!()\[\]{};:\'".,<>?\xab\xbb\u201c\u201d\u2018\u2019]))',line):` am i doing it write like u suggested

Comment: With the URL example given, I can't reproduce your problem.

Comment: @Evert u ran my program.? with the sample website with https://?

Comment: I ran `import urllib; urllib.urlopen("https://support.makemytrip.com/MyAccount/MyTripReward/DashBoard")` with Python 2.7.10 on OS X. Which returns `<addinfourl at 4467648632 whose fp = <socket._fileobject object at 0x109102250>>`.

Comment: Im on Fedora with Python 2.7 which i installed in VMware . Do u Have any idea y it is not working in mine  @Evert

Comment: Can you access the URL on that machine + OS using wget, curl or a browser?

Comment: yes Page can be access from firefox in fedora

Comment: Can you `import ssl` and `import _ssl` without problems?

Comment: @Evert When i use curl it give me this error for both http and https: `curl: (5) Could not resolve proxy: proxy4.nehu.ac.in; Cannot allocate memory`
When i use wget it is working its shows Connected . what seems to be the problem ?any idea....i am stuck here .

Comment: Yes i can import both.